# How can I get elementFromPoint() to return an SVG g element?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm using [document.elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) to pick out `g` elements from a complex SVG over which I have control. I want a specific `g` element that has many children nested within it, and in order to obtain that `g` element I'm setting `pointer-events: none` on the child elements. I expect `elementFromPoint` to return the nearest parent with standard values for `pointer-events` because that's now `elementFromPoint` seems to work in HTML.

Here's an sample that demonstrates the way in which SVG seems to work differently that HTML:

```js
// The point at the center of #html-child
// Returns the #html-parent element, as I expect. GOOD!
console.log(document.elementFromPoint(100, 100).id);

// The point at the center of #svg-child
// I expect it return the #svg-parent element.
// Instaed it returns the <svg/> element. FRUSTRATING!
console.log(document.elementFromPoint(100, 300).id);
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<!-- A 200px x 200px square with html -->
<div id=html-parent>
  <div id=html-child
    style='width: 200px; height: 200px;
      background: black;
      pointer-events: none'
  ></div>
</div>

<!-- A 200px x 200px circle with svg -->
<svg viewBox='-100 -100 200 200' width=200 height=200 id="svg-container">
  <g id=svg-parent>
    <circle id=svg-child x=0 y=0 r=100 pointer-events=none />
  </g>
</svg>
```

I'm aware that I can remove `pointer-events: none` and then traverse the DOM to find my `g` element. But for performance reasons I'd like to avoid that approach because this code runs within a 'touchmove' event listener that fires very frequently. I'd also like to understand why the SVG behaves differently than the HTML.

**How can I get `elementFromPoint` to return the `#svg-parent` element?**

Comment: SVG2 has a `bounding-box` value for `pointer-events` but only Chrome supports it for now.

Comment: I think there is no way to set a namespaceURI in  elementFromPoint()

Comment: Check the parent of the element you get.